# IKVM.targets(17, 9): [MSB4018] The "IkvmGetReferenceAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly after adding Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP in .net core 6.0 project

Tags: c#, nlp, .net-6.0

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this issue for me.

I have a new .net core 6.0 API project and want to do some NLP processing

using a mac air m1

I have installed a package Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP and right away I am getting this error..

IKVM.targets(17, 9): [MSB4018] The "IkvmGetReferenceAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
at IKVM.Tool.Compiler.IkvmCompilerLauncher.GetToolDir(IkvmCompilerTargetFramework framework, OSPlatform platform, Architecture architecture) in D:\a\ikvm\ikvm\src\IKVM.Tool\Compiler\IkvmCompilerLauncher.cs:line 107
at IKVM.Tool.Compiler.IkvmCompilerLauncher.GetReferenceAssemblyDirectory(IkvmCompilerTargetFramework framework, OSPlatform platform, Architecture architecture) in D:\a\ikvm\ikvm\src\IKVM.Tool\Compiler\IkvmCompilerLauncher.cs:line 151
at IKVM.Tool.Compiler.IkvmCompilerLauncher.GetReferenceAssemblyDirectory(IkvmCompilerTargetFramework framework) in D:\a\ikvm\ikvm\src\IKVM.Tool\Compiler\IkvmCompilerLauncher.cs:line 163
at IKVM.MSBuild.Tasks.IkvmGetReferenceAssemblies.GetReferenceAssemblies()+MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToArray() at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at IKVM.MSBuild.Tasks.IkvmGetReferenceAssemblies.Execute() in D:\a\ikvm\ikvm\src\IKVM.MSBuild.Tasks\IkvmGetReferenceAssemblies.cs:line 44
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask)